# Autohotkey numpad mouse script, events propagating to some programs, but not others

Tags: autohotkey

I have an issue when trying out one of the example scripts in the autohotkey docs:

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/NumpadMouse.htm

When a program like Notepad++ gets focus, the script does not seem to receive key events, and instead the key events seem to be consumed by Notepad++.

Is there a modification to the script that would allow it to receive the events no matter what window was open?

Comment: In Windows 7, I needed to make sure AutoHotKey had admin privileges or this behavior would occur... Once it was given admin, other programs were unable to intercept the hotkeys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7, I needed to make sure AutoHotKey had admin privileges or this behavior would occur... Once it was given admin, other programs were unable to intercept the hotkeys.